# Create all possible subsequence with unique elements

Tags: python, algorithm, sequence

I have a sequence of elements of the form:

A111 **T112** I113 A114 S115 I116 D117 F118 K119 R120 E121 T122 C123 V124 V125 V126 **T112**

with the constraint every element to occur only once. In the above sequence T112 occurs twice. So I need to create all possible subsequences that satisfy the constraint, namely:

**T112** I113 A114 S115 I116

I116 K119 R120 E121 T122 C123 V124 V125 V126 **T112**

In a more complicated scenario I have the following sequence that must satisfy the same constraint:

A111 **T112** I113 A114 **T112** S115 **I116** D117 **I116** K119 R120 E121 T122 C123 V124 V125 V126

This time T112 but also I116 occur twice. In this case I need the following subsequences:

A111 **T112** I113 A114

I113 A114 **T112** S115 **I116** D117

D117 **I116** K119 R120 E121 T122 C123 V124 V125 V126

Of course an element may occur more than 2 times. Is there any efficient way to solve this problem without using a genetic algorithm?

Comment: You need to give more sample inputs and outputs. I'm still unsure of *exactly* what you want.

Comment: I think I can see what the subsequences should be but could you make it clearer? What are the actual rules?

Comment: what's the delimiter of each sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
list  = ["A111", "T112", "I113", "A114", "T112", "S115", "I116", "D117", "I116", "K119", "R120", "E121", "T122", "C123", "V124", "V125", "V126"]

subsequence = []
for item in list:
    if item in subsequence:
        print subsequence
        index = subsequence.index(item)+1
        subsequence = subsequence[index:]
    subsequence.append(item)
print subsequence
```

Will print:

```
['A111', 'T112', 'I113', 'A114']
['I113', 'A114', 'T112', 'S115', 'I116', 'D117']
['D117', 'I116', 'K119', 'R120', 'E121', 'T122', 'C123', 'V124', 'V125', 'V126']
```

Comment: Clever! It work also for more complicated cases like the following:  list = ["A111", "T112", "I113", "A114", "X100", "I116", "X101", "T112", "S115", "I116", "D117", "I116", "K119", "R120", "E121", "T122", "C123", "V124", "V125", "V126"]

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a running set, to track what strings repeat:

```
def partitions(s):

    lst = s.split()
    flags = set()
    for l in lst:
        if l in flags:
            yield list(flags)
            flags.clear()
        flags.add(l)
    yield list(flags)

>>> s = "A111 T112 I113 A114 T112 S115 I116 D117 I116 K119 R120 E121 T122 C123 V124 V125 V126"
>>> x = partitions(s)
>>> print list(x)
[['A111', 'I113', 'T112', 'A114'], ['D117', 'S115', 'T112', 'I116'], ['R120', 'T122', 'E121', 'V125', 'V124', 'V126', 'C123', 'K119', 'I116']]
```